# Localise validation error form json file in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, translation

i am using json file based translation, but not able to translate FormRequest validation error from json file.

Problem i am facing is FormRequest is returning localised error form resource/lang/xx/validation.php but i want translations from resource/lang/xx.json

example:

```
class CreateSampleRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'               => 'required|string|regex:/^[^{}<>]{1,200}$/',
            'regCode'            => 'required|string',
            'address'            => 'required|string',
            'phone'              => 'required|string',
            'email'              => 'required|email',
            'contactPerson'      => 'required|string',
            'personCode'         => 'required|string',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: could you include your code?